# Insert Page break in Richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005, richtextbox

How to insert Page Break in RichTextBox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.bokko.nl/adding-a-pagebreak-in-a-richtextbox-for-printing/) for you.

The `\\page` indicates the beginning of a new page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... but what i am doing is: loading the entire RTF File into Richtextbox using LoadFile Command, Copy-Paste into Second Richtextbox and then assigning the 2nd Richtextbox to string that holds the RTF. This all happens in for loop and thus when combining 2 or more RTF there is no page break in it. I tried @Page for RTF but that didn't worked. Any idea for Richtextbox.

Comment: Maybe this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/902b1cdf-8346-4a79-888c-cd607b1a4ebb (last post)

Comment: The link is dead now :(

Answer (score 0):

I appended chr(12) in my VB application (that is the Form Feed ASCII character) to insert a page break.  Note that you won't see the page break in the Rich Text Box, but it will appear if you save it and open the file in Word, or if you print the contents.

There are RTF control codes documented here: 
[Rich Text Format 1.5 specification](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)
that you can use, but inserting Chr(12) worked well enough for me.